# Can I use advertisements with community license for dot42?

Tags: licensing, ads, dot42

I want to start making apps for Android and I want to know if I can start safely with free license and see if I can make some money with advertisements inside my apps. So my question is can I do that?

> The Community License is free. It does not permit any form of
>   commercial use. Furthermore, the Community License allows you to
>   publish free apps on a public market place such as (but not limited
>   to) Google Play or SlideME.

It seems like kind of commercial use, but then again, the application would be free...
If the answer is no, would you recommend some other way of making apps that would be free? HTML5? Java with Eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would rely on a lawyer aswering that question then on software engineers (the latter are only found here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ads inside your app is considered commercial so you would need the Pro license. You may start without ads with the community license. See how your audience grows and then move to the Pro license when you feel it pays off.

Comment: Yes, its clear from their agreement http://www.dot42.com/licensemodel.aspx your app is NOT free if you use advertisements, the client 'pays' with unwanted things and you get money for it or not?